# Bootloop after hibernation

Tags: windows-8.1

Yesterday I put my windows 8.1 laptop in hibernation. Next morning I forgot about hibernation and pressed the power key to boot it up. Now it's stuck on the dell logo and the loading spinner won't appear. This had happened in the past but somehow startup repair fired up and fixed the issue and it booted up. Any help regarding fixing this will be greatly appreciated as I have an assignment due this week. Some key points- I currently don't have the disc image of windows with me. I have dual booted windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.01. If somebody could tell me how to go into startup repair, that'd be pure gold. Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just remove the battery and then reapply it

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few working solutions, but since you havent mentioned what did you do else than just put hibernation on (for example, was there any updates you downloaded / installed, what updates those were? etc) you should just check the suitable option from here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/how-to-fix-the-automatic-repair-loop-in-windows-81/bfc92bc7-031f-45d4-b623-bcb4847d32fd

Comment: No I didn't install any updates and no it isn't an automatic repair loop, just the dell logo displaying indefinitely.